# Opposite tag to @Override in Java

Tags: java, methods, overriding, superclass, annotate

I know that in Java is tag `@Override` to annotate method which overrides method from superclass, if not there is a warning.
My question: is there an opposite tag to annotate method which we do not want to override method from superclass (eg. by accident)?

I know that I can set method in superclass `final`, but this solution involves changes in superclass code. That's what I don't want to do - just want to change my code :)

I know that I can set another name for this method, but sometimes in super class there is a lot of methods and you simply not aware of them. So when you implement your own in subclass you might by accident use the same name. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no *pre-defined* Java annotation that is the inverse of `@Override`.

Having said that,  most IDE's should be able to identify if a method is overriding another. For instance Eclipse has this feature. If you look at your class in Outline view, you'll see a small triangle where overrides occur. For example:

[image]

I have to believe that NetBeans and IntelliJ Idea must have similar functionality.

---

As an aside, this problem that you're trying to address, that of avoiding inadvertently overriding a parent method, is a serious and pernicious one, one that has an especially elevated risk when extending classes that have many methods or a large inheritance hierarchy (think Swing components as an example -- I once had a majorly frustrating GUI bug due to my tripping over accidentally overriding JPanel's `getX()` and `getY()` methods). This is another reason to in general prefer composition over inheritance if composition makes sense in the situation.

Comment: However, you can build something like this yourself using JSR-308 (type annotations) and the Checkers framework.  See: http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/

Comment: @BrianGoetz: If you can show how to do this, how to specifically create an annotation that will allow the compiler to warn you of unexpected overrides, please post this as an answer.

Comment: Same issue here! I accidentally override `getHeight` and `getWidth` method and spent over hour debugging and wondering why this is not working! :)

Comment: @bartektartanus: yep! In my brief one-off programs, I'll have large classes that extend a Swing component, but in my serious programs, I try to avoid this when possible (except when necessary, such as when `paintCompnonent` needs to be overridden).

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting this warning in NetBeans even though I was not in fact overriding the method. I was just invoking a subclass method from within the subclass constructor and NetBeans was flagging this as an override.

Even though there is no inverse @override tag, a simple solution is to just make the method private instead of public/protected if you know you won't be overriding it or using it anywhere below the subclass that it's in.

Comment: This works unless parent class was written by someone else and I dont have access or I don't want to edit this code. :)

Comment: When extending someone else's class which is in a different package, this is the answer. If you declare a method without public or protected, you will get an error saying that you cannot reduce the visibility of the super's method. You don't need to change the super's code.

Answer (score 0):

Give the method in the sub-class a different name or signature than the method in the super-class that you wish to not override.

Comment: I know that I can set another name for this method, but sometimes in super class there is a lot of methods and you simply not aware of them. So when you implement your own in subclass you might by accident use the same name. How to avoid this? [I also added this to question]